# Topic Challenge: Michael Mann and his films

Tags: discussion, challenge

Last week saw the release of [*Michael Mann*](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000520/)'s new movie [*Blackhat*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2717822/) and due to [popular opinion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1513/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge from 2015-01-19 00:00 UTC to 2015-01-26 01:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about ***Michael Mann* in general or any of the films he directed/wrote, or the TV-shows he ran**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [michael-mann](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/michael-mann) tag to each and every of those questions, [tag responsibly](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1293/49) instead.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were **no** questions asked about the topic during the challenge.

Comment: I hope Johnny Depp doesn't do the same.