# Removing inappropriate tags after question is answered?

Tags: discussion, tags

Not trying to go over heads here but thought this was an appropriate question to bring up here.

On [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30672/what-is-the-name) recent topic, I asked this question and I thought it might be good to get some opinion/discussion.

> I know the OP thought this was animated but it is NOT... as it seems to be Pleasantville... should the animated tag be removed? Is this the sort of thing that should be asked on Meta? Generally, should inappropriate tags be removed when the question is answered.

And I received the following reply:

> Probably not. When he thinks it's animated, then that's part of his question. If that turns out to be wrong, we're not supposed to alter the question to fit to the answers. That's not different from adding a "[SOLVED]" appendage to the question title. Though, in this particular case it is not entirely clear if the tag was originally intended to express that the searched movie was animated or if it was simply added for lack of tagging experience and the fact that a cartoon supposedly played a role at some part of the movie. –  Napoleon Wilson

My question then becomes:

> I understand not changing the **question** to suit the answers... on one of the other stacks I frequent, particularly [Seasoned Advice], it can become very problematic, but if the purpose of the tags is to help people find similar questions, wouldn't this be (have been, since the tag was removed) mis-categorized?

I'm guessing there can be some room for interpretation as some people throw on more tags than necessary and there seem to be several questions about when particular tags are appropriate in the first place (eg. the directors discussion [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/when-should-a-director-tag-be-used-created)).

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that, as a repository of Q&A it's probably best to make things easily and accurately searchable.  Many people misremember "facts" about the show and then later remember that it's not what they thought.  So, if the question is tagged as a cartoon and then discovered to **not** be a cartoon (via an accepted answer), then that cartoon tag is counter-productive to the site.

Leave it there until an answer is accepted, but then remove it.