# Topic Challenge: The Wachowskis and their films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

Last week saw the release of [*The Wachowskis*'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wachowskis) new movie [*Jupiter Ascending*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1617661/). This might be a chance to recapitulate the whole oeuvre of the *Wachowski* <s>brothers</s> siblings, from [bound](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bound) over [the-matrix](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-matrix) and [v-for-vendetta](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v-for-vendetta) to [jupiter-ascending](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jupiter-ascending)... So due to [popular opinion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1498/49) we're starting a new **weekly topic challenge. From 2015-02-09 00:00 UTC to 2015-02-16 01:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic question on the main site about **the *Wachowskis* and the films written/directed by them**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question/answer votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [wachowskis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wachowskis) tag to each and every of those questions, [tag responsibly](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1293/49) instead.</sub>

Comment: Really interested to see question on Matrix , cloud atlas and  V for Vendetta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 15 and ~183 views) was asked by [*Catija*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/16420), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Switch in *The Matrix* - Two Actors?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/30884/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [How is the Wachowskis' interpretation not up to the mark according to Alan Moore?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/30974/49) (6 / ~294)
3. [Inspiration for making Speed Racer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/31054/49) (5 / ~334)
4. [Wachowski trademarks?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/30968/49) (4 / ~75)

Comment: Interesting how it works out.  Got the most upvotes but nearly the fewest views.

Comment: @Catija Well, which speaks even more for the question, since the smaller the views, the larger the votes per view, so more of the people who actually looked at it at all also found it a good question.

Comment: @Catija: You should be asking what you get. I think Napoleon needs to send you a tee shirt, or something!

Comment: @AndrewMartin YAY! I want a shirt! Do topic challenges on other sites have prizes? Honestly, it would even be cool if there was a Badge for it that was just awarded by the mods... though I'd recommend that it requires the question to have a **positive** rating.

Comment: Oh, and @NapoleonWilson I actually am a female.

Comment: @Catija They had on other (larger and older) sites in the past (but I'm not sure how that's now). But that would require quite a bit of official backing. That being said, with the current challenge activity and the IMHO largely coincidental entries to it, I'm not sure it would be feasible/justifyable at all. I considered putting limited bounties on the winners, but you can't put a bounty on a question, maybe for the *unanswered questions* challenge coming in the near future that might be a good idea.

Comment: Though, if anyone has any other reasonable ideas for possible challenge rewards/improvements, the [suggestion box](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) is always open.