# Topic Challenge: Steven Spielberg and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Last week saw the 40th anniversary of the release of [*Jaws*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073195/), the movie that marked [Steven Spielberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Steven_Spielberg)'s breakthrough onto the blockbuster olympus. This might be a good chance to give his large body of work a thorough retrospective and ask some engaging questions about his various movies. So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1818/49) we're starting a new **biweekly topic challenge from 2015-06-22 00:00 UTC to 2015-07-05 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **Steven Spielberg and the films directed by him**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [steven-spielberg](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steven-spielberg) tag to each and every of those questions, [tag responsibly](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1293/49) instead.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 13 and ~120 views) was asked by [*DForck42*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/52), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why the large gap in Indiana Jones movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35698/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [How did Spielberg come to direct Ready Player One?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35699/49) (2 / ~78)

Comment: guess i was the only one interested in this one... :-/