# Topic Challenge: Wes Craven and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

Last sunday saw the death of [*Wes Craven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wes_Craven), who looked back upon more than 4 decades of contributing to the shape of the horror and thriller genres, from creating iconic figures like *Nightmare on Elm Street*'s Freddy Krueger to spearheading the 90s revival of teen slashers with the *Scream* series. So to honor him and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1903/49) we decided to start a **topic challenge from 2015-09-01 00:00 UTC to 2015-09-11 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **Wes Craven and the films written or directed by him**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [wes-craven](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wes-craven) tag to each and every of those questions, [tag responsibly](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1293/49) instead.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **top-voted question** (with a score of 5 and ~112 views) was asked by [*Tom Cody*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [What happened to Robert Englund?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/40789/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why was the Ghostface mask changed in the TV series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/40723/49) (3 / ~51)