# Topic Challenge: Quentin Tarantino and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

With the release of writer/director [*Quentin Tarantino*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quentin_Tarantino)'s latest film [*The Hateful Eight*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3460252/) and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1935/49) we are starting a **topic challenge from 2016-01-09 00:00 UTC to 2016-01-17 23:00 UTC** asking for any kind of question about **Quentin Tarantino and the films written or directed by him**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [quentin-tarantino](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quentin-tarantino) tag to each and every of those questions, [tag responsibly](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1293/49) instead.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the **only and thus top-voted questions** (with a score of 0) were asked by [*Tloz*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/19458) and [*yaapelsinko*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/29690), which makes them the winners of this challenge:

## 1. [Animals on movie sets - the cat in The Hateful Eight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46368/49)

## [Pumpkin and Honey Bunny from Pulp Fiction - did they appear in another movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46030/49)