# Topic Challenge: Tim Burton and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

August 25th celebrates the 58th birthday of renowned director [*Tim Burton*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Burton). So in honour of him and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2378/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2016-08-23 00:00 UTC to 2016-09-03 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Tim Burton and the [films written or directed by him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Burton_filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [tim-burton](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tim-burton) tag to each and every of those questions, [tag responsibly](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1293/49) instead.</sub>

Comment: I even missed when it got proposed but sounds good to me.

Comment: Does it also include movie he appeared in? Though he has cameo appearances only. I only watched two movies (one as director and another as actor).

Comment: @AJ No, unless the question relates directly to him.

Comment: Truly the man's 58th birthday is an important milestone to celebrate!

Comment: @Thunderforge Sure it is.  Why wouldn't it be?  _Every_ birthday is a milestone to celebrate.  Also, movie channels such as HBO will run the director or actor's films on the week that their birthday falls on, at least in the U.S.  HBO has been running his films for over a week, now.  Doesn't matter if it's his _58th_ birthday or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 20 and ~4317 views) was asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [What was Bruce Wayne's obsession with unusual looking statues?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60101/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why is Betelgeuse named after a star?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59934/49) (12 / ~916)
3. [What was the purpose of Christopher Lee's scene with the eagle wings behind him?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60011/49) (10 / ~114)

   [Is there a specific term or name for Tim Burton's Gothic dark comedic style?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59942/49) (10 / ~1089)
4. [Is Harley Quinn based on Alicia Hunt?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60034/49) (9 / ~171)
5. [Did the Joker kill Alicia Hunt?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59989/49) (8 / ~117)

   [Was the actress Winona Ryder laughing in the dinner scene or was it in the script?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59968/49) (8 / ~142)
6. [What was the significance of dinosaur hedge-sculpture made by Edward?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59868/49) (7 / ~68)
7. [Where did the line about the reason for the big eyes come from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60021/49) (6 / ~55)
8. [Where did the theory of Batman being a mob enforcer come from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60169/49) (5 / ~42)

   [Why is the cathedral in such a mess?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60182/49) (5 / ~309)

   [Why did Tim Burton create a similar windmill scene both on Frankenweenie and Sleepy Hollow?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60060/49) (5 / ~356)
9. [Why did filmmakers choose to portray Jack Napier as the murderer of Bruce Wayne's parents?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59798/49) (4 / ~153)
10. [Why was Josette under a sheet?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59929/49) (2 / ~33)

Comment: I want to thank my mom, dad, sister, sister's dogs, friends and reatives and last but not the least steelerfan for giving me the idea and for suggesting the topic and Napoleon to successfully run the challenge.