# Topic Challenge: Milla Jovovich and Paul W. S. Anderson [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

End of January saw the release of [*Resident Evil: The Final Chapter*](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2498/49), the latest installment in a series that marks the collaboration between writer/director [Paul W. S. Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_W._S._Anderson) and actress [Milla Jovovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milla_Jovovich). So [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2498/49) we're stating a new **topic challenge. From 2017-02-06 00:00 UTC to 2017-02-12 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **films either [written/directed by Paul Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_W._S._Anderson#Filmography) or [starring Milla Jovovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milla_Jovovich#Filmography)**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add [paul-w-s-anderson](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paul-w-s-anderson) or [milla-jovovich](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milla-jovovich) tags to each and every of those questions, [tag responsibly](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1293/49) instead.</sub>

Comment: For those wondering why Paul W. S. Anderson and Milla Jovovich are linked, they have been married since 2009.

Comment: @Thunderforge Thanks for that clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 31 and ~4,059 views) was asked by [*sanpaco*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22993), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why did Korben Dallas leave the military?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68402/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Did Korben engage in a fight in The Fifth Element?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68250/49) (9 / ~361)
3. [Is the Alice in the end of Resident Evil Apocalypse a clone or the real one?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68227/49) (7 / ~359)
4. [Does Ruby Rhod fall under rainbow umbrella, is it even established in the film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68274/49) (6 / ~163)
5. [Why was K-Mart's name changed from the original draft script?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68278/49) (5 / ~65)

Comment: Yay! I am on second place.

Comment: Woot! Acceptance speech: thanks to AJ and Ankit Sharma and others for encouraging me to participate in the ToW. Thanks for HNQ for advertising my question which is why it got more votes and views. And thanks to Bruce Willis and Milla Jovovich for The Fifth Element. Bada boom!

Comment: And I am not last \o/