# Topic Challenge: Christopher Nolan and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

With the release of [*Dunkirk*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5013056/) and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2521/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-07-22 00:00 UTC to 2017-07-30 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **[Christopher Nolan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Nolan) and the [films written/directed by him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Nolan#Filmography)**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [christopher-nolan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christopher-nolan) tag to each and every of those questions, [tag responsibly](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1293/49) instead.</sub>

Comment: So are we meant to ask a question as an answer (down below) or as a proper answer to an ordinary question. Reason I have asked is because I have never done one of these before.

Comment: @natural You have to ask any question on the  films written/directed by Nolan to participated, highly voted question will be considered winner  but to make it clear there is no real prize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 22 and ~3,335 views) was asked by [*steelersquirrel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Was Ra's al Ghul nearly immortal in the Dark Knight trilogy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77763/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [What is the significance of the robot names in Interstellar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77848/49) (14 / ~1,055)
3. [Is there any CGI used in Dunkirk?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77871/49) (7 / ~2,801)
4. [What are the parallels between Angier/Borden and Edison/Tesla?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78049/49) (6 / ~41)
5. [Why is there not any bullet wound in this character in Dark Knight Rises?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77764/49) (4 / ~303)

   [What is the explanation of "act of killing a bug"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77816/49) (4 / ~87)
6. [What exactly is the old man at the end of Dunkirk going through while distributing food to the survivors?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77815/49) (3 / ~829)
7. [Why did Collins not eject his seat when his plane was about to crash?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77769/49) (2 / ~540)

   [Who drowned in the beached ship?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77808/49) (2 / ~190)
8. [Why is the movie Following (1998) shot in black & white?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77860/49) (-2 / ~64)

   [How does he end up alone?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78028/49) (-2 / ~65)

Comment: Acceptance speech:  Wow!  I cannot believe that I won this challenge!  I admittedly do not appreciate Christopher Nolan's work like others on this site do _cough_ Napoleon and Ankit.  I was prompted to participate in this challenge so that I can start appreciating Mr. Nolan's work more.  Thank you to Ankit for "urging" me to participate ;), to Napoleon for providing an awesome answer and for my other chat buddies, AJ and S S for participating with me!!! <thanking the little people> :P