# Named Director Tags

Tags: discussion

I noticed recently that we have a few tags which are specific to *individuals* such as...

[alfred-hitchcock](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alfred-hitchcock) 11 Questions

[steven-spielberg](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steven-spielberg) 6 questions

[tim-burton](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tim-burton) 1 Question

...just to name a few. I'm sure there are others.

The tag wikis are good enough but it seems to me that we should **only** be using these tags for specific questions abou the director or specific overall questions about their work. This [previous question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/when-should-a-director-tag-be-used-created) from a few years back doesn't seem to have set any specific rules

For instance [stanley-kubrick](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stanley-kubrick) is attached to this question:

[In Dr. Strangelove, what is the device Soviet Ambassador Sadesky uses near the end of the film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57546/in-dr-strangelove-what-is-the-device-soviet-ambassador-sadesky-uses-near-the-e)

The tag adds nothing to the question which asks nothing about the director at all.

So, should we :

- Update the tag wikis as to their usage
- Review from the questions to which they *are attached* (there aren't many) and remove as needed

  - *perhaps as we find them to avoid clogging the front page?*

Or pehaps we just remove them completely since we already have an overarching [directors](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directors) tag sitting there for use?

I'm torn but the first option seems most user-friendly.

Comment: It seems to have set pretty much specific rules through the consensus of its answers, namely that they're only to be used when the question is actually related to the director.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the director or any individual person tag should be used for questions about that person (not about personal lives as comment by @Catija) or his/her working style, given that those questions are within the scope defined in [help center](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

For eg., [Why did Nolan want to end the Batman series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3399/27264) and [Why did Nolan choose “Non, je ne regrette rien” as a kick song in Inception?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1974/27264).

In conclusion, unless the question is about an individual person or his/her working style, the individual tag must not be used.

Comment: But note that the personal lives of actors/directors are not appropriate topics for this site.

Comment: @Catija Ahh.. this is why I added `given that those questions are within the scope defined in help center.`