# What's the correct way of using filmmaker tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

From some recent posts, I noticed that there is a [christopher-nolan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christopher-nolan) tag, with [19 questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christopher-nolan) altogether. I'm not familiar with M&TV policy on filmmaker tags, and two related sister sites have very different policies (Literature [uses author tags on every question](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1619/17) while SFF [uses author tags almost only for questions about the author themselves rather than their works](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/31394)), so it's not obvious to me how such tags are supposed to be used here. The tag wiki is no help, containing no usage guidance.

- Obviously this tag is not used on all questions about Nolan films, as for example [inception](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inception) has 95 questions and [memento](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memento) has 38 questions, way more than the Nolan tag.
- But it's also not being used only on questions that are specifically about Nolan himself (rather than his films) or about his films as a whole (so any individual-film tag wouldn't work): for example, [these](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/86309/27759) two [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/119822/27759) are run-of-the-mill questions about individual Nolan films.

**What is the correct usage of the Nolan tag and others like it?** If there's already a clear policy on this, please link me to it (I couldn't find anything on meta about it). If not, should we make one and do some editing if necessary to put actual tag usage in line with how the tag is supposed to be used?

Comment: This discussion did happen before few times https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/when-should-a-director-tag-be-used-created  and https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/named-director-tags

Answer (score 4):

We should adopt the same methodology as SF&F.

It should be used for questions regarding

> a) aspects of the author's life, or b) aspects of the author's work that are not specific to a single work or franchise, then we tag the question with the name of the author

I see no reason to add a "director" tag any more than an "actor" tag to a question unless the question relates specifically to something relating to that person since that is irrelevant to the question at hand

In cases such as the two examples linked the tag should be removed but a complete purge is probably unfeasible and they should be removed as they are found.

A brief search (a couple of minutes) of possible tags for question review found these in short order:

[akira-kurosawa](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akira-kurosawa)
[alan-moore](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alan-moore)
[alan-smithee](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alan-smithee)
[alfred-hitchcock](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alfred-hitchcock)
[george-lucas](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-lucas)
[tim-burton](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tim-burton)
[joss-whedon](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joss-whedon)

Comment: Thanks. If this answer gets consensus, I'll edit my meta question to include a list of all "tagged Nolan but shouldn't be" questions. Do you know of any other filmmaker tags here apart from Nolan?

Comment: I'm sure there are some. [tag: stanley-kibrick] comes to mind. I confess, my established unofficial policy has been to remove these from questions unilaterally in such cases. If I have time (and the inclination) I may browse through the tag list and check.

Comment: This answer actually has *been* consensus for basically the last 10 years.

Comment: I cleaned up a bit of Nolan. Most of it is rather recent (since we tend to remove them as they arise and not many directors elicit them). But there's probably quite a few old relics. Removing them along the way as we usually do probably works without cluttering the frontpage too much.

Comment: Indeed.... no need for a mass purge.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Sorry, I didn't find the older posts when I poked around a bit before creating this. On the other hand, it seems to me that the answers here and on the 2017 post are clearer and less ambiguous than the more wishy-washy response to the 2014 post ([summarised pithily by a commenter as "IDK LULZ"](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/when-should-a-director-tag-be-used-created#comment2919_1293)). I'm not sure if switching dupe directions would help at all to create a clearer policy post to refer to?

Comment: @Rand al'Thor The "IDK LULZ" comment in the older question was posted before the [current top-voted answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1310/1006) was posted. I think that the answer provides a clear policy.