# Topic Challenge: M. Night Shyamalan and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

With the release of [*Glass*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6823368/) and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4368/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2019-01-20 00:00 UTC to 2019-01-31 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **[M. Night Shyamalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Night_Shyamalan) and the [films directed by him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Night_Shyamalan#Filmography)**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add an [m-night-shyamalan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-night-shyamalan) tag to each and every of those questions, [tag responsibly](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1293/49) instead.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 10 and ~171 views) was asked by [*Matt*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/31394), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [What is the significance of the black spot in M. Night Shyamalan’s “Glass”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96578/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Is Glass self-explanatory?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96622/49) (8 / ~318)
3. [Do we ever get to know the clear motives of the aliens?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96682/49) (3 / ~124)
4. [How does Elijah escape his cell?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96669/49) (-1 / ~73)