# Should we close questions about inconsistent plots as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I saw a few questions about the Transformers franchise and the movie scripts are full of inconsistencies. Question like "[why don't they use lasers in combat when they had lasers to open up a ship made of the same metal](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100519/why-dont-the-autobots-use-their-lasers-in-combat)" and the [different ways to kill a Transformer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101568/how-do-transformers-die).

Since the answer is, essentially, bad writing, should we mark these type of questions together as duplicates and have a canonical answer to rule'em all? Should we accept  questions when the only answer is an obvious plot hole? Is it really constructive (as asked before [here on Meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/yes-that-was-a-plot-hole-and))?

Something in the lines of [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/101571/19762), perhaps more generic.

> The complete and utter lack of consistency in death within a story (besides being a Micheal Bay movie) is the common trope of “Plot Armour”
>
> > Sometimes referred to as "Script Immunity" or a "Character Shield", Plot Armor is when a main character's life and health are safeguarded by the fact that he's the one person who can't be removed from the story. Therefore, whenever Bob is in a situation where he could be killed (or at the least very seriously injured), he comes out unharmed with no logical, In-Universe explanation.

Answer (score 3):

## No

Firstly, we no longer have "Not Constructive" close reason.

At best it could be argued that the answer is "Opinion-based" and closed for *that* reason.

---

It's also, perhaps, relevant to point out that what is **currently** a "plot-hole/inconsistency" MAY be cleared up in a future movie/show in the same universe.

---

However, the real danger here is that users will reach for that close vote option where, in fact, an in-universe reason might exist.

As I said elsewhere..

> Sometimes the answer to a question is "We don't know" or "The movies aren't consistent" and **should be answered on that basis.**
>
> That doesn't make the question invalid/bad/unworthy even if, in our heads, we're thinking "well that's obvious".

**If the answer is "Yes, it's plot-hole" then so be it.**

Users can Upvote/Downvote on the answer as they wish but closing the question probably isn't useful.

Comment: But in cases of "yes, it's a plot hole" could we have one canon and mark the rest as dupes? at least for questions about the same movie or the same franchise?